# How to show user specific data on the list based on a many to many relationship using Symfony 5 EasyAdmin Bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

I am very new to EasyAdmin bundle. I was trying to load user specific content in the list of a logged in user.

So here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/asset": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/intl": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/string": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/translation": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.0.*"
},
```

I have a Project Requirements entity which has a many to many relationship with the User entity like the following:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="projectRequirementsHasUserProjectRequirements")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_requirements_has_user",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_requirements_has_user_project_requirements_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_requirements_has_user_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $projectRequirementsHasUserUser;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->projectRequirementsHasUserUser = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

So when adding requirements I can assign user like this:

[image]

You can see that the first requirements has assigned to 2 users:

[image]

**Now I want to show all the requirements which has assigned to the logged in user.**

I came to know that I need to override the default EasyAdminController, so I configured my entity in `config/packages/easy_admin.yaml`:

```
    # Project Planning
    ProjectRequirements:
      controller: App\Controller\ProjectRequirementsController
      class: App\Entity\ProjectRequirements
```

And then create a controller but don't know how to write the filter or query to select only the requirements which has assigned to the logged in user:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;

class ProjectRequirementsController extends EasyAdminController {

protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{

    /** @var QueryBuilder $result  */
    $result = parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);




    return $result;

}
```

}

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot about 2 days finally I understand how EasyAdmin and Symfony `QueryBuilder` works. It was nice to find the solution by myself. So here is what I came up with the solution:

```
# App\Controller\ProjectRequirementsController.php

protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
    /** @var QueryBuilder $result  */
    $result = parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);

    # Getting data User wise
    $result->leftJoin('entity.projectRequirementsHasUserUser', 'user')
    ->andWhere('user.id = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());

    return $result;

}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've created a ManyToMany unidirectional connection. Try using bidirectional mapping like described in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

Then you should easily access your logged in user's assignments via the array collection in the user entity.

Comment: I am sorry, but I guess the relation is bidirectional. Do you have any idea how to filter these array collection in EasyAdmin?

Comment: How are you configuring / creating your form?

Comment: I did nothing @Martin M. I just let everything handled by EasyAdmin.

Comment: You can use a built-in dynamic filter of type entity in your config file like here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#built-in-dynamic-filters

Comment: It is not about filtering data but joining, see my answer, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To show user specific data in the list, you need to add an argument on the $dqfilter.

```
// Creates the Doctrine query builder used to get all the items. 
// This will override the original method.
protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
     // If the parameter is equal to null, we set the parameter to user id
     if (null === $dqlFilter) {
         $dqlFilter = sprintf('entity.author = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
     } else {

     // If the parameter is not null, we add a new parameter (user id) to the $dqfilter
         $dqlFilter .= sprintf(' AND entity.author = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
     }
    
    return parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);
}

// Creates the Doctrine query builder used to look for items according to the
// user's query. Override this method if you would not like that user can see other data after doing search query
protected function createSearchQueryBuilder($entityClass, $searchQuery, array $searchableFields, $sortField = null, $sortDirection = null, $dqlFilter = null)
{
   if (null === $dqlFilter) {
        $dqlFilter = sprintf('entity.author = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
   } else {
        $dqlFilter .= sprintf(' AND entity.author = %s', $this->getUser()->getId());
   }

   return parent::createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter);
}
```

Comment: This will not work in my case because if you see carefully you will find that there is no direct field in the main table. There are many to many relation with the User, so `entiry.author` will not work. Oh! by the way i have found the solution, check my accepted answer below.